# Calculate frequency of dummies using filter and dplyr - R

Tags: r, dplyr, sum

I have a dataframe ('df.feather') where  variables are: empem3112 (dummy employment status), year and cnpjcei (company ID)

```
df > 
empem3112  year     cnpjcei
 1          2009    4774
 1          2009    4774
 0          2009    4774
 1          2009    4774
 0          2009    4774
 1          2009    3567
 1          2009    3567
 1          2009    3567
 1          2009    4774
 1          2009    3567
 1          2009    1224
 1          2009    1224
 1          2009    1224
 1          2009    1224
```

Basically, I want to calculate the absolute frequency of the two possible outcomes of the dummy "empem3112" grouping by year and company ID

I tried to use the following commands:

```
teste = rais2009 %>%
  group_by(ano, cnpjcei) %>%
  summarise(
    total = sum(empem3112),
    empreg = sum(empem3112[empem3112==1]),
    deslig = sum(empem3112[empem3112==0]))
```

And the outcome is:

```
   ano      cnpjcei       total empreg deslig
   <dbl>    <chr>          <int>  <int>  <int>
 1  2009     4774         6        6      0
 2  2009     3567         4        4      0
 3  2009     1224         4        4      0
```

But this result is not correct, since for all companies there is at least 1 employee with the status "empem3112==0"

Suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, but you are summing the _values_ of `empem3112`, not the _length_. Any sum of 0s will be 0. Change your `sum`s to `length`s

Comment: Ahh, I hadn't thought of that! Thanks, Allan!  :)